# How to access the callback status twilio when the call is finished?

Tags: php, api, callback, twilio

I'm trying to access the status AFTER the call is done, and display it in the first page, not in the callback page.

i have calling page:

```
require 'twilio/Services/Twilio.php';
$sid = "xxx"; // Your Account SID from www.twilio.com/user/account
$token = "xxx"; // Your Auth Token from www.twilio.com/user/account

$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);
try {

$call = $client->account->calls->create(
  '000', // From a valid Twilio number
  $number, // Call this number

  // Read TwiML at this URL when a call connects (hold music)'
  "http://myurl.com/voice.xml", array('Method' => 'GET','StatusCallback'=>'http://myurl.com/callback.php'));
    if($call->status =='failed')result(array('status'=>'failed status '));
    else result(array('status'=>$call->status));

} catch (Exception $e) {
        result(array('status'=>'not a valid number'));
    }
```

my issue is that i'm not understanding how i can get the $_POST info that twilio will send to my callback.php on my calling page.php....

Answer (score 0):

Please read Twilio API explaintion [Click here for reference from Twilio Site](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#status-callback-parameter-request-parameters) to know the post parameters from Twilio on your callback back page.

**http://myurl.com/callback.php**

```
$callDur = $_POST['CallDuration']; 
$recdDur  = $_POST['RecordingDuration'];
```

To get these values on other page store them in session and use them where you want.